# Key Value store option for Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, key-value-store

Is there any plugin available for Jenkins which provides a key-value store option for Jenkins? 
The plugin which's functionality is close to that is the credentials plugin.
The goal is to have a plugin which stores global configuration parameters and this parameters are available to Jenkins jobs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Manage jenkins -> Configure System -> Global Properties -> Environment Variables:

[image]

**Check the box and Click on `ADD`**

[image]

**Enter Key-value and Save**

To access the variable simply `${<Your-key>}`

Answer (score 0):

Could the enthronement variables fit your need?

They are like regular shell variable.

If you are using the pipeline you can define it this way:

```
environment {
    VAR = 'your_value'
}
```

and use it later in your build.
This is explained there: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/environment/

If you are writing your pipeline from the UI, you can add a 'source' step in your build step.

```
source your_environnement_setting
test='Hello'
```

And then the variables can simply be used like any shell var:

```
echo $test
```

If you have variables that you do not know in advance, but you know when you are triggering your job, you can also use the parametrized plugin:
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build